# ODP.NET 12c Remove Schema Prefix in Dataset Designer

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, visual-studio, odp.net

When creating Tableadapter query in Dataset Designer the schema prefix is added automatically before table name. How to stop this behaviour ?

The Displayed schemas cannot be empty

[image]

Comment: I requested that your screenshot be deleted because it is not related to the question. A relevant screenshot might be the TableAdapter wizard or Dataset designer.  I think that you are going to have to manually edit the dataset.xsd file to deal with this but I will check to see if there are any options. Note that a given user can have permissions on multiple schemas which can each have identical table names in them, which is why the schema name is included.

Comment: You don't have to manually edit the xsd file. See below.

Answer (score 0):

The schema name is auto generated if you drag and drop table names from Server Explorer or if you use Query Designer. You cannot disable this auto generation. However, once it is created,  if you look at the properties from the TableAdapter, you can modify the SQL there and remove the schema name if you wish.

You can also enter the SELECT statement directly into the TableAdapter Configuration wizard and if you do not launch the query designer it will not add the schema name.

Comment: Manually editing the query is an obvious option but my question is regarding the query designer

Comment: You can't stop the schema name from being added once you are in the query designer. By the way, your screenshot shows how you control what schemas are included under the Server Explorer tree control. It has nothing to do with appended schema names in any of the designers.